# Cytoscape with Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, cytoscape.js, angular13, cytoscape-web

I am a big fan of the cytoscape.js chart and I almost used so many types of the cytoscape.js chart without angular or react. Now I am trying to find out a working git repo that cytoscape.js chart with the angular 13 version. I also got a [git repo](https://github.com/calvinvette/ngx-cytoscape) from the official cytoscape.js website, but it's not working properly. Seems the cytoscape.js developers are not concentrated on the angular wrapper. Any one have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a package to use it.

```
npm i cytoscape
npm i -D @types/cytoscape
```

This will install the library and the typings for it.

You can use

```js
import { whatever } from 'cytoscape';
```